# JS - Remove Active from all, add active to target

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im pretty new to Web Development, so I am sorry for this stupid question.

I have 4 Divs with different classes.

Icon-feature1 - 4 and each of them has a different active class.
I want that my JS is removing all actives and adding active on the targeted (clicked) div.

The class "master-feature" I added to have all of the Divs something in common and be able to be selected. It's maybe not the best way, but I came up with this and thought it's okay.

```js
let swapactive = document.getElementsByClassName('master-feature');
for (let i = 0; i < swapactive.length; i++) {
  swapactive[i].addEventListener('click', activateClass);
}

function activateClass(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < swapactive.length; i++) {
    swapactive[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  e.target.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.icon-feature1 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  content: url("/static/img/feature1_blue.svg");
  animation: pulsate 3s ease-out infinite;
}

.icon-feature1.active {
  content: url("/static/img/feature1.svg");
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 pb-10">
    <div class="active icon-feature1 master-feature">
    </div>
    <div class="p-3 pt-3 col-content-box col-features-active col-features-not-active col-round-border col-feature">
      <p id="fs-16">
        <b id="fs-18">Feature 1</b><br/> Feature 1 Description
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="icon-feature2 master-feature">
        </div>
        <div class="p-3 pt-3 col-content-box col-features-not-active col-round-border col-feature">
          <p id="fs-16">
            <b id="fs-18">Feature 2</b><br/> Feature 2 Description
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="icon-feature3 master-feature">
        </div>
        <div class="p-3 pt-3 col-content-box col-features-not-active col-round-border col-feature">
          <p id="fs-16">
            <b id="fs-18">Feature 3</b><br/> Feature 3 Description
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="icon-feature4 master-feature">
        </div>
        <div class="p-3 pt-3 col-content-box col-features-not-active col-round-border col-feature">
          <p id="fs-16">
            <b id="fs-18">Feature 4</b><br/> Feature 4 Description
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I click a div, nothing is happening. What did I made wrong?
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, your code seems to be working fine. Is there any content in the original div? Also does the active class have additional styles?

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi the active class has a different icon than the icon-feature class. and  it stops an animation which is played for non-active icons. The div has no other content, beside the icon.svg.

Comment: It would be helpful if  you could share the full code

Comment: Not the _full code_. Only the least amount necessary to reproduce the problem -> [mcve] :)

Comment: I added this blog with the sub-divs so you can reproduce the problem maybe better :-) also included the css

Comment: Use `e.currentTarget` instead and your code works.

Comment: @connexo thank you so much, that was the problem :-O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target` and your code works.